# Retrieve name in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

In MySQL, there has a table named admin, with 3 columns which are adminID, name and password.

I wanted to compare the id and name from user input with the data in the MySQL. If id and password matched, display the name. However, the value of the name display is always null.

```
  public boolean checklogin(String id, String Pass)throws Exception  
            {
                boolean check=false;
                String name = null; // because assigning null here ? 
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM admin WHERE adminID =? and password= ?" ;
                DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
                Connection  conn =db.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement  ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                ps.setString(1, id);
                ps.setString(2, Pass);
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
                admin lg=new admin();
                lg.setID(id);
                lg.setPassword(Pass);
                lg.setName(name);

                if(rs.next())
                {
                    check =true;
                    System.out.println(lg.getName());
                    ps.close();
                    rs.close();
                    conn.close();
                    return check;       
                 }
             }
```

What's wrong with my code? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think `name` should not be null?? I mean it's null on the commented line and never assigned after that, so..

Comment: @RC. what is the correct way to retrieve the name from MySQL to `name` variable ?

Comment: `rs.getString("name")` probably, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/

Comment: @RC. where should I add that line ?

Comment: What happens when rs.next() == false ? You have syntax error here, function should return something also in this case... Note: I have missed that there is no getString call...

Comment: @JohnJoe please read the fancy tutorial I linked

Comment: @RC. OK. Thanks :)

Comment: As @RC. said, rs.getString("name") or rs.getString(column_no_of_name) should do the task. Inside the if block.

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia thanks, solved :)

Comment: @igr solved,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your not displaying the name from the database but the name you assigned which is null. You need to replace `System.out.println(lg.getName());`  with `System.out.println(rs.getString("name"));`